# TS-Node: Could not find sourceFile

Tags: javascript, typescript, file-not-found, ts-node

My project has been using `ts-node` to run a mix of JavaScript and TypeScript.  Recently it stopped working, without an obvious reason.  At the most simple level, here is how it's run and the error it produces:

```
$ TS_NODE_PROJECT=./tsconfig.json ../../node_modules/.bin/ts-node app.js                                                                                   MSTR-1513
INFO   | Arrow/1.6.0
No deployment manifest found
Uncaught Exception Could not find sourceFile: '/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/server/src/v1/route/Routes.ts' in [].
Error: Could not find sourceFile: '/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/server/src/v1/route/Routes.ts' in [].
    at getValidSourceFile (/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:122211:23)
    at Object.getEmitOutput (/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:122580:30)
    at getOutput (/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:354:30)
    at Object.compile (/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:473:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:476:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Excerpt of `app.js`:

```
const Routes = require('./v1/route/Routes').default;
server.app.use('/v1', new Routes().router);
```

I'm very confused by this part of the error: `Could not find sourceFile: '/Users/jonah/Projects/myapp/server/src/v1/route/Routes.ts'`.  I can paste that exact path into the terminal and and see that the file does in fact exist.  Here is `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {

    "allowJs": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny" : false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "watch": false,
    "types": ["mocha"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./v1/**/*.ts",
    "../test/v1/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Running currently latest of TypeScript (3.5.2) and ts-node (8.3.0).  What type of circumstances might produce this kind of error?  I've even tried messing around with the `include`s to make sure the file being imported is covered.  Running the TypeScript compiler on its own works just fine.

```
../../node_modules/.bin/tsc --project tsconfig.json
```

Comment: I had a similar problem today (ts-node in combination with `Could not find sourceFile`)
Changing the order of the imports helped. Not sure if sth similar helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this has to do with circular dependencies. Especially with the answer from @Brenne saying:

> Changing the order of the imports helped.

These kind of inexplicable errors have always tended to be circular dependencies in my experience.

I'm only familiar with the [webpack plugin to detect these](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin). However, you can play around with removing the require and seeing if it builds properly.  From there, remove pieces other requires/imports from the `'./v1/route/Routes'` file to see if any of those are causing the circular dep

Answer (score -5):

Im not to familiar with tsc because i always use babel with webpack, but i think u need to enable the `allowJs` option if u want to compile the js to ts.